# Factory Girl link tables with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

Want to create the related records for the related tables:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :product_cstm, :foreign_key=>'id_c'
end

class ProductCstm < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = 'product_cstm'
self.primary_key = 'id_c'
belongs_to :product, :foreign_key=>'id_c'
end
```

So tables are linked with Products.id and Product_cstm.id_c

I've created following factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :product do
   id_c { SecureRandom.uuid }
 end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :product_cstm do
   accociation :product_cstm
 end
end
```

Is it possible to create factories (and records), where the UUID would be generated the same for both product.id and product_cstm.id_c?

Answer (score 1):

Umm not sure why you've two factories with the same name.

Associations need to be done within the same block. So something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :product do
        id_c { SecureRandom.uuid }
        association: product_cstm, strategy: :build
    end
end
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on questions which still don't have answers. Thanks.